# Суммировать значения input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно сложить значения неизвестного кол-ва input.
Сумму вывести в другой input.
В ещё один input вывести через запятую все значения input, которые суммировали

```html
<input class="input-small" value="2">
<input class="input-small" value="5">
<input class="input-small" value="3">
...... - кол-во может быть разным

<input id="sum" value=""> - тут сумма
<input id="vse" value=""> - тут все значения суммированных input по порядку через запятую
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let sum   = document.getElementById('sum');
let all   = document.getElementById('all');

let small = document.querySelectorAll('.input-small'); 
let numbers = []; // Массив, куда запишутся все значения инпутов

for( let i = 0; i < small.length; i++ ){
  numbers.push( small[i].value ); // (*1)
  
  small[i].addEventListener('input', function(){
    numbers[i] = this.value; 
    // При вводе чисел в любом инпуте, не будем пересобирать все значения, 
    // а только изменим конкретный элемент массива. 
    // this - указывает на инпут, в котором печатают (который запускает эту функцию)

    // Все значения в массиве обновлены, можно обновить и результаты:
    updateResults();
  });
}
updateResults();

/************/

function updateResults(){
  sum.value = sumArr( numbers );
  all.value = numbers.join(', ');
}

function sumArr(arr){
  let x = 0;
  for( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
    x += +arr[i]; // (*2)
  }
  return x;
}
```

```css
input {margin: 2px 0;}
```

```html
<input class="input-small" value="2"><br>
<input class="input-small" value="5"><br>
<input class="input-small" value="3"><br>
<button id="ok">ok</button><br>

<input id="sum" value=""><br>
<input id="all" value="">
```

(*2): arr[i] - это small[i].value, вставленное в массив в строчке `(*1)`. А это строка. 
Т.е. 0 + '2' == '02'. Чтобы не было этой ошибки, нужно превратить его в число. Можно было бы `Number( small[i].value )` но есть короткий вариант - поставить плюсик перед ней.

А `x += число` то же самое, что `x = x + число`

Comment: Спасибо! А нереально сделать, чтобы без нажатия кнопки (меняешь значение в исходном input и сразу пересчитывается сумма и значения подставляются в all?

Comment: @user305361 Отредактировано)

Comment: И подскажите пожалуйста как переписать, чтобы считались числовые поля <input class="input-small"  type="number" value="" min="0" max="10">. Если вводить число вручную, то пересчитывает, а если пользоваться стрелками поля, то скрипт не воспринимает такое изменение value.

Comment: `small[i].addEventListener('input', function(){ numbers[i] = this.value; updateResults(); });` — эту строчку можно повторить, только заменив событие input на `change`

Answer (score 0):

Решил сократить и протестировать.

```js
let priceInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.js-p-input');
let arrNumbers = [];

priceInputs.forEach((item, inx) => {
  
  //arrNumbers.push(item.value);//убрав, при вводе в 10й input получим [,,,,,,,,,1]
  item.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');//лочим всё кроме цифр.
    arrNumbers[inx] = this.value;

    console.time()
    let sum1 = getSumInputs(arrNumbers);
    console.timeEnd()

    console.time()
    let sum2 = sumArr(arrNumbers);
    console.timeEnd()
  });
});


function getSumInputs(arr){//[,,,,,,,,,1] reduce совершит 1 итерацию
  return arr.reduce((prev, num) => {
    console.dir('Итераций Reduce'); 
    return (prev += +num)
  }, 0);
}
 //ради сокращённой записи arr.reduce((prev, num) => (prev += +num), 0);
function sumArr(arr){//[,,,,,,,,,1] совершит 10 итераций
  let x = 0;
  for( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
    console.log('Итераций for'); 
    x += +arr[i]; 
  }
  return x;
}
```

```css
input{
  display: block;
}
input+input{
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
  <input class="js-p-input" type="text"  placeholder='1'>
  <input class="js-p-input" type="text"  placeholder='2'>
  <input class="js-p-input" type="text"  placeholder='3'>
  <input class="js-p-input" type="text"  placeholder='4'>
  <input class="js-p-input" type="text"  placeholder='5'>
  <input class="js-p-input" type="text"  placeholder='6'>
  <input class="js-p-input" type="text"  placeholder='7'>
  <input class="js-p-input" type="text"  placeholder='8'>
  <input class="js-p-input" type="text"  placeholder='9'>
  <input class="js-p-input" type="text"  placeholder='10'>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]